# Passing where clause as a func

Tags: entity-framework, func

I have broken out the where clauses in my applications to their own libraries and then pass them to the database at run time.  This was done to help with testing.

I attached a log to the db to see what the generated sql was and I noticed that the where clause was not listed.  The data is still filtered, so that causes me to believe that the data is filtered in the app instead of in the database.  Can anyone confirm this?  Is there a better way to do this?

Here is a sample:

**Where Clause**

```
private Func<Message, bool> GetSearchWhere(string q, string type)
{
    return m => m.Name.Contains(q) && m.Type == type;
}
```

**DB Call**

```
private List<Messages> GetMessages(Func<Message, bool> where)
{
     return Messaging.Messages.Where(where).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is indeed filtered in memory by LINQ to Objects. When you pass `Func<T, bool>` to `Where` method, you actually are calling [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want to call [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040(v=vs.110).aspx) (thus making the filtering in the database), then you need to pass `Expression<Func<T, bool>` instead.

To do that, all you need is to change the signature of your methods:

```
private Expression<Func<Message, bool>> GetSearchWhere(string q, string type)
{
    return m => m.Name.Contains(q) && m.Type == type;
}

private List<Messages> GetMessages(Expression<Func<Message, bool>> where)
{
     return Messaging.Messages.Where(where).ToList();
}
```